# Gzweb documentation development

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is little on how Gzweb works. I am interested in developing such a document. I am wondering what help/references/procedure may be there (in addition to reading the source code). Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13008/gzweb-documentation-development/) by [Yuanlin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2533/yuanlin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Most of the existing information about GzWeb is on the following page. There are instructions on how to install, run and develop GzWeb, as well as a user guide for the GUI.

http://gazebosim.org/gzweb

Most of that content is pulled from tutorials. These are the install and run instructions:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gzweb_install&cat=gzweb

And these are the development instructions:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gzweb_development&cat=gzweb

For the javascript code, you can generate documentation running the [following](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gzweb/src/db9376b50d2ed7772cadac6ef447328d5828f9ad/updateGZ3D.sh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) from the gzweb root directory:

```
./updateGZ3D.sh -d
```

And open it on a browser like this:

```
firefox gz3d/doc/index.html
```

As far as I know, this is all the documentation available. Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yuanlin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2533/yuanlin/) on 2016-04-05**:
Thanks for the useful information!